# Loaded image does not appear in Django template 1.8

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django development
and I have a problem I do not know where the error is.

Follows some excerpts from my code:

My settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "media_root")
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    #url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

    url(r'^home/$', 'newsLetter.views.home', name='home'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My views.py

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        formOBJ = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if formOBJ.is_valid():
            instance = formOBJ.save(commit=False)

            instance.save()

            for key in request.FILES.getlist("photos"):

                IMX = SugnUpIMG.objects.create(signup_id=instance.id, photos=key)

            contexto = {
                "tituloForm"    : "Obrigado!",
                "vFlag"         : 1,
                "img"           : SugnUpIMG.objects.filter(signup_id=instance.id,)
            }
    else:

        titulo = "Escreva aqui a sua mensagem na home"

        contexto = {
        "tituloForm": titulo,
        "Formulario": SignUpForm(),
        "UploadIn"  : SugnUpIMGForm()
        }   

    return render(request, 'home.html', contexto)
```

My home.html

```
<img width="240" height="240" border="1" scr="{{ fotos.photos.url }}" alt="{{ fotos.photos }}">
```

Here everything works correctly, the files are saved in the correct folder, however
I can not view them in the Template.

The URL of the image is thus in HTML.
[image]

And it appears that way.
[image]

But when I put the URL of the image at the address

127.0.0.1:8000/media/projectimg/2542601-play-games.png

it is displayed in the browser.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: I dont see `fotos` context variable being rendered

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and is now functioning as intended
I was in html tag where modified to:

```
<img width="240" height="240" border="1" src="{{ fotos.photos.url }}">
```

I did not understand why the alt attribute have prevented the display of the image?
Has anyone ever experienced this?